# Standard Problem on Mathematical-Induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** For $n\ge 1$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j^2}\leq 2-\frac{1}{n}$$
**Proof.** We construct the proof by recourse to *Mathematical-Induction*.

For $n=1$ we see that $\sum_{j=1}^{1}\frac{1}{1} = 1\leq \frac{3}{2} = 2-\frac{1}{2}$ establishing the basis of the induction.

Now let $k$ be arbitrary and assume for $k$ that 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{j^2}\leq 2-\frac{1}{k}$$ consequently 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{j^2} = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{j^2}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\leq 2 - \frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$$
but observing the following equivalence 
$$2 - \frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} = 2-\left(1+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{k+1}$$
together with the fact that $k\ge 1$ implies that 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{j^2}\leq 2-\left(1+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{k+1}\leq 2-\frac{1}{k+1}$$
completing the inductive step.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: The base case has a type I think. You have that $\sum_{j=1}^1 \frac{1}{j^2} = 1 \leq 2 - \frac{1}{1} = 1$ and not $\frac32$.

Comment: Thank you i did not see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Personally I would elaborate the equation $$-\frac1k+\frac1{(k+1)^2} = -\left(1+\frac1{k(k+1)}\right)\cdot\frac1{k+1}$$
It is correct but not directly obvious. I had to check it on a paper too...

But all in all your proof is good.